# Wordpress get_the_excerpt() is returning a string "Summary"

Tags: php, wordpress

I am calling `get_the_excerpt()` in my `functions.php` file in WordPress. Currently having an issue that the excerpt is adding the string "Summary" to the end of the string. How do I remove this? 
NB: I don't want to preg replace the string just in case someone actually types a summary in the excerpt box or in the post content.

The code i am using is:

```
$excerpt = wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_excerpt($postId));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a plugin conflict with Rich Snippets.